# How to find CPU shutdown temperature? (Think it's called TJMax, maybe not though...)

Tags: 12.04, power-management, cpu, temperature

In Windows there is a program called CPU Temp which shows various CPU temperatures, one which being the temperature at which point the computer will shut down to prevent damage to the CPU.

I have a script which will intelligently prevent the CPU going over a certain temperature, but I would like to know what temperature I can go up to :D

Comment: Usually you can get operating temperatures from the manufacturer's specification.

Comment: You can genrally get this by using lm_sensors - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2780

Comment: What CPU do you have?